# How to create a program to list all the USB devices in a Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, iokit

I have a limited exposure to the Mac OS X operating system and now I have started using Xcode and am studying about I/O kit. I need to create a program in Xcode under command line tool in order to list all USB devices connected in a Mac system. Those who have previous experience under this, please help me. If anyone could provide me with sample code then it will be of great use, as I am looking for starting point.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can adapt [USBPrivateDataSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/USBPrivateDataSample/Listings/USBPrivateDataSample_c.html) to your needs, the sample sets up a notifier, lists the currently attached devices, then waits for device attach/detach. If you do, you will want to remove the `usbVendor` and `usbProduct` matching dictionaries, so all USB devices are matched.

Alternately, you can use [`IOServiceGetMatchingServices`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOKitLib_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_66) to get an iterator for all current matching services, using a dictionary created by `IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName)`.

Here's a short sample (which I've never run):

```
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOKit/usb/IOUSBLib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    CFMutableDictionaryRef matchingDict;
    io_iterator_t iter;
    kern_return_t kr;
    io_service_t device;

    /* set up a matching dictionary for the class */
    matchingDict = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName);
    if (matchingDict == NULL)
    {
        return -1; // fail
    }

    /* Now we have a dictionary, get an iterator.*/
    kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, matchingDict, &iter);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    /* iterate */
    while ((device = IOIteratorNext(iter)))
    {
        /* do something with device, eg. check properties */
        /* ... */
        /* And free the reference taken before continuing to the next item */
        IOObjectRelease(device);
    }

   /* Done, release the iterator */
   IOObjectRelease(iter);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is very useful and this is similar to what iam looking for. when i build it but this code is showing errors like error: IOServiceGetmatchingServices referenced from _main in main.o ...Similar errors for _IOObjectRelease,_IOServiceMatching,_IOIteratorNext,_kIOMasterPortDefault..I created a project under xcode->Command line tool->standard c++. If you may help, i will be very thankful to you

Comment: Errors which i got while building.................


Undefined symbols:
  "_kIOMasterPortDefault", referenced from:
      _kIOMasterPortDefault$non_lazy_ptr in main.o
  "_IOServiceGetMatchingServices", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_IOObjectRelease", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
  "_IOServiceMatching", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_IOIteratorNext", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You need to use the I/O Kit framework (ie. `IOKit.framework`) and Core Foundation frameworks in your project, or this won't link.

Comment: thanks. Now building is successful and program runs too. As i told before i just need to list the usb devices. please help me with some command which will just list usb devices. i was just looking for some  sample code like this, this is very helpful to me.

Comment: /***Display the device names ***/....................
         
  io_name_t  deviceName;
  kr = IORegistryEntryGetName(device, deviceName);
  if (KERN_SUCCESS != kr) {
            deviceName[0] = '\0';
        }    
  printf("\ndeviceName:%s",deviceName);.........................this gives me device name...Now iam looking for program which is dynamic that is which also shows attaching and detaching of devices..Pls help

Comment: @DILi: Check out the USBPrivateDataSample I linked to, it uses attach/detach notifications.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to access the IOKit *Registry*. You may well be able to use the `ioreg` tool to do this (e.g. run it via `system()` or `popen()`). If not then you can at least use it to verify your code:

Info on `ioreg` tool:

```
$ man ioreg
```

Get list of USB devices:

```
$ ioreg -Src IOUSBDevice
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It will be very helpful for verification. But i need a program in xcode(in c++) for listing the usb devices

Comment: Did you read the part about using `system()` or `popen()` to execute the ioreg tool from within your code ?

Comment: I read it. but i was looing for something like the code given below by hausturkun. this too is useful. but if you give some sample code like i said it will be the best.

Answer (score 3):

If you run `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` it'll list all the USB devices connected to the system, you can then interact with that data either by dumping it into a text file or reading it from the command into the application and working with it there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Swift version to list connected USB devices:

```
import IOKit
import IOKit.ps
import IOKit.usb

func findMatchingPorts() -> Bool {
    
    print("------------------")
    print("findMatchingPorts")
    print("------------------")

    var matchingDict : CFMutableDictionary?
    
    var iter : io_iterator_t = 0
    var kr : kern_return_t
    var device : io_service_t
    
    /* set up a matching dictionary for the class */
    
    matchingDict = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName)
    
    if matchingDict == nil {
        
        // no matching ports
        
        print("no matching ports")
        
        return false
        
    }
    
    /* Now we have a dictionary, get an iterator.*/
    
    kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(
        kIOMasterPortDefault,
        matchingDict,
        &iter
    )
    
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        
        // fail
        
        print("fail")

        return false
        
    }
    
    /* iterate */
            
    repeat {
        
        device = IOIteratorNext(iter)

        guard device != 0 else {
            
            break
            
        }
        
        /* do something with device, eg. check properties */
        /* ... */
        /* And free the reference taken before continuing to the next item */
        
        print("device: \(device)")
        print(device.name())
        
        // release device reference
        
        IOObjectRelease(device)
        
    } while (true)
    
    /* Done, release the iterator */
    
    IOObjectRelease(iter)
    
    print("done")

    return true
    
}

extension io_service_t {
    /// - Returns: The device's name.
    func name() -> String? {
        let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<io_name_t>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        defer { buf.deallocate() }
        return buf.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: MemoryLayout<io_name_t>.size) {
            if IORegistryEntryGetName(self, $0) == KERN_SUCCESS {
                return String(cString: $0)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```